# Encrypt long data with 3DES ECB using OpenSSL in C++

Tags: c++, encryption

I have an example of encryption with 3DES which correctly encrypts a string of 8 values, this is the example:

```
void encript3DES()
{
    unsigned char out[8] = {0};

    des_cblock key1 = {0x85, 0xAC, 0xDA, 0x3F, 0x31, 0x87, 0xC5, 0x57};
    des_cblock key3 = {0x85, 0xAC, 0xDA, 0x3F, 0x31, 0x87, 0xC5, 0x57};
    des_cblock key2 = {0x3E, 0x43, 0x7E, 0xDE, 0x55, 0x6D, 0x4B, 0x5B};

    des_key_schedule ks1, ks2, ks3;

    unsigned char in[8] = {0x42, 0x13, 0x16, 0x60, 0x62, 0x18, 0x78, 0x63};

    int i = 0;

    DES_set_key((C_Block *)key1, &ks1);
    DES_set_key((C_Block *)key2, &ks2);
    DES_set_key((C_Block *)key3, &ks3);

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
    {
        printf("0x%02X, ", in[i]);
    }

    printf("0x%02X\n", in[i]);

    DES_ecb3_encrypt((C_Block *)in, (C_Block *)out, &ks1, &ks2, &ks3, DES_ENCRYPT);

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
    {
        printf("0x%02X, ", out[i]);
    }

    printf("0x%02X\n", out[i]);
}
```

- INPUT DATA: **4213166062187863**
- KEY: **85ACDA3F3187C5573E437EDE556D4B5B85ACDA3F3187C557**
- OUTPUT DATA: **43B5EBBA7F282362**

I need to encrypt a string of 24 characters instead of 8 using the same key, I think this function only encrypts strings with length of 8 that is why I modified the previous example to achieve the encryption of a string of 24, however the result does not is the expected, this is the modified function:

```
void encript3DES()
{
    unsigned char out[24] = {0};

    des_cblock key1 = {0x85, 0xAC, 0xDA, 0x3F, 0x31, 0x87, 0xC5, 0x57};
    des_cblock key3 = {0x85, 0xAC, 0xDA, 0x3F, 0x31, 0x87, 0xC5, 0x57};
    des_cblock key2 = {0x3E, 0x43, 0x7E, 0xDE, 0x55, 0x6D, 0x4B, 0x5B};

    des_key_schedule ks1, ks2, ks3;

    unsigned char in[24] = {0x42, 0x13, 0x16, 0x60, 0x62, 0x18, 0x78, 0x63, 
                            0xD2, 0x00, 0x42, 0x21, 0x08, 0x23, 0x81, 0x27, 
                            0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF};

    int i = 0;

    DES_set_key((C_Block *)key1, &ks1);
    DES_set_key((C_Block *)key2, &ks2);
    DES_set_key((C_Block *)key3, &ks3);

    for (i = 0; i < 23; i++) 
    {
        printf("0x%02X, ", in[i]);
    }

    printf("0x%02X\n", in[i]);

    for(int incr = 0; incr <= 24; incr += 8)
    {
        DES_ecb3_encrypt((C_Block *)in + incr, (C_Block *)out + incr, &ks1, &ks2, &ks3, DES_ENCRYPT);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 23; i++) 
    {
        printf("0x%02X, ", out[i]);
    }

    printf("0x%02X\n", out[i]);
}
```

Could someone help me to get the right encryption?

- NEW INPUT DATA: **4213166062187863D20042210823812700000FFFFFFFFFFF**
- KEY: **85ACDA3F3187C5573E437EDE556D4B5B85ACDA3F3187C557**
- NEW OUTPUT DATA: **43B5EBBA7F28236200000000000000000000000000000000**
- DESIRE OUTPUT DATA: **43B5EBBA7F2823623D13732603C453138C0D98E88B8F25C7**

Comment: Looks like you are incrementing wrong type of pointer - use `(C_Block *)(in + incr)` and for out as well

Comment: Yep, looks like casting to `C_Block` and then adding `incr` times the length of `C_Block` instead of increasing with the byte. The `+` in C on pointers behaves compared to the type it is working on. Noe, please provide feedback if this works or not.

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky works fine! Thanks

Comment: @MaartenBodewes yes it works with Artemy solution